# Changing raspberry pi bluetooth device name?

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am trying to change a raspberry pi's bluetooth name to something else (an ip address) so that when I scan and pair my android device it will see this ip as the device name. It worked once but then went back to appearing as "raspberrypi-0"

I have tried both the hciconfig set name command, and have also changed the device name inside /etc/bluetooth/main.conf but still all my device sees is "raspberrypi-0". Its driving me crazy so if anyone knows what the issue is please help!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you want to change the bluetooth device name permanently, you have to create a file called /etc/machine-info which should have the following content:

```
PRETTY_HOSTNAME=device-name
```

Then issue "service bluetooth restart" after that

Answer (score 12):

**@Evangelos Nannos** answer still works (BlueZ 5.50) but if you want to change bluetooth alias on the fly you may try *bluetoothctl* (tested on *Pi Zero W* running *Raspbian Stretch* & *BlueZ 5.50*)

To set new alias open terminal:

```
    pi@raspberrypi:~ $ bluetoothctl
    [bluetooth]# system-alias 'Your New BT Alias'
    Changing Your New BT Alias succeeded        
    [CHG] Controller AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF Alias: Your New BT Alias
```

Use *show* to see current bluetooth settings:

```
    [bluetooth]# show
    Controller AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF
    Name: Some_other_name #default or as PRETTY_HOSTNAME
    Alias: Your New BT Alias #alias will be shown when scanning for bt devices
    (...)
```

Reset alias and go back to using system device name with:

```
    [bluetooth]# reset-alias
```

Exit bluetootctl with:

```
    [bluetooth]# quit
```

---

With **Discoverable on (yes)** the device will show up during scaning as **Your New BT Alias**.

Take note that **alias will be kept after reboot!**

I've use pexpect to manipulate bluetoothctl, bash works too. There were problems registering Agent on BlueZ 5.43 via pexpect, had to upgrade to 5.50

---

**Alternative command (note it will not return a response):**

```
    pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo hciconfig hci0 name 'New device name'
```

Comment: Nice that this only affects bluetooth

Answer (score 1):

It stores the display name in /var/lib/bluetooth/xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx/config file. If you wants to change the bluetooth display(broadcast) name then you need to follow the below steps:

1. delete /var/lib/bluetooth/xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx/config file.
2. Edit /etc/bluetooth/main.conf(For ex: Name=%d-%h to Name=abcd-5)
3. service bluetooth restart.

Note: If this already paired with some other BT devices, so you need to remove the pairing to see the new BT name of the same device(MAC).

Answer (score 1):

You can also just disable the hostname plugin and configure the name.

Run `sudo vim /etc/systemd/system/bluetooth.target.wants/bluetooth.service`
and append `--noplugin=hostname`, like this:

```
ExecStart=/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd --noplugin=hostname
```

Then edit the bluetooth config and set your desired name:
`sudo vim /etc/bluetooth/main.conf`

```
Name = YourNewName
```

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the below steps

step 1 - write below code in terminal

```
sudo nano /etc/machine-info
```

step 2 - It will open a blank file, Now write this line into it

```
PRETTY_HOSTNAME=PutYourDeviceNameHere
```

step 3 - Now restart Bluetooth service OR You can reboot Raspberry Pi

```
service bluetooth restart
```

OR

```
sudo reboot
```

Hope it's Work For you

Answer (score 0):

Use `hostnamectl` command for change or set your bluetooth name.

```
hostnamectl --pretty set-hostname <PutYourDeviceNameHere>
```