# Raspberry Pi as a audio Transmitter to a Bluetooth Speaker

Tags: audio, raspberry-pi, bluetooth

Is it possible to use the Raspberry Pi as a transmitter from a audio source, lets say a TV for example?
I want to send the sound from the TV to the Raspberry Pi via audio Jack and then send the sound via Bluetooth to a wireless speaker. So the Raspberry should act like a bridge between TV and the speaker.

**It should look like this in the end:**

> TV --*Sound via audio jack*--> Raspberry Pi ~~*Sound via Bluetooth*~~>
> speaker

So, if there is a way, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

RPi doen't have audio input. You need one of these adapter like this (http://raspberry-projects.com/pi/pi-hardware/audio-input) and connect input to TV and RPi output to wireless / bluetooth speakers. I haven't tried it yet. Let me your feedback.

Answer (score 2):

Since a web search might bring others here as it did me, here's how I did this connecting my record player through a Raspberry Pi 3 to a Bose Portable Home/Smart Speaker.

#### Get an audio input into the Pi

I used a cheap USB soundcard bought on Adafruit

#### Identify your new PulseAudio input/source and note name

This can be done by calling `pactl list sources` (mine was identifiable from its name and description)

```bash
$ pactl list sources
...
Source #2
        State: RUNNING
        Name: alsa_input.usb-GeneralPlus_USB_Audio_Device-00.mono-fallback
        Description: USB Audio Device Mono
...
```

#### Connect your Pi to your bluetooth speaker

1. Run `sudo bluetoothctl` (running this without `sudo` resulted in settings being forgotten upon reboot) and enter the commands below
2. (Optional) [Give your Pi an alias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54554983/952932) when connecting over bluetooth: `[bluetooth]# system-alias 'Your New BT Alias'`
3. Enter scanning mode `[bluetooth]# scan on`
4. Put your speaker in pairing mode and wait for it to be listed in the rolling output. E.g.

```
[NEW] Device AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA AA-AA-AA-AA-AA-AA
[NEW] Device BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB BB-BB-BB-BB-BB-BB
[NEW] Device CC:CC:CC:CC:CC:CC My speaker's name
```

5. Pair with it referencing its address:

```
[bluetooth]# pair CC:CC:CC:CC:CC:CC 
Attempting to pair with CC:CC:CC:CC:CC:CC
[CHG] Device CC:CC:CC:CC:CC:CC Connected: yes
Request confirmation
[agent] Confirm passkey 123456 (yes/no): yes
```

6. Connect to the speaker now

```
[bluetooth]# connect CC:CC:CC:CC:CC:CC 
Attempting to connect to CC:CC:CC:CC:CC:CC
[CHG] Device CC:CC:CC:CC:CC:CC Connected: yes
Connection successful
```

7. Trust the speaker so it is automatically connected to when available

```
[My speaker's name]# trust CC:CC:CC:CC:CC:CC 
[CHG] Device CC:CC:CC:CC:CC:CC Trusted: yes
Changing CC:CC:CC:CC:CC:CC trust succeeded
```

#### Note your bluetooth speaker's associated PulseAudio output/sink name

This can be done by calling `pactl list sinks` (again, should be identifiable by name and description)

```bash
$ pactl list sinks
...
Sink #2
        State: RUNNING
        Name: bluez_sink.CC_CC_CC_CC_CC_CC.a2dp_sink
        Description: My speaker's name
...
```

#### Set up PulseAudio defaults

1. Identify a good volume level for your input so distortion is minimal. E.g.

```
pactl set-source-volume alsa_input.usb-GeneralPlus_USB_Audio_Device-00.mono-fallback 16000
```

2. Add your version of the following lines to `/etc/pulse/default.pa` to [set up an audio loopback](https://askubuntu.com/a/262297/112715) and ensure the correct devices (based on the names you noted above) are used by default:

```
### Make some devices default
set-default-sink bluez_sink.60_AB_D2_57_42_A9.a2dp_sink
set-default-source alsa_input.usb-GeneralPlus_USB_Audio_Device-00.mono-fallback

# Set up loopback
load-module module-loopback latency_msec=1

# Set input volume
set-source-volume alsa_input.usb-GeneralPlus_USB_Audio_Device-00.mono-fallback 16000
```

Comment: I ended up having to set up Pulse to run [system-wide](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/SystemWide/) for this to work without needing an active SSH session. Will update when I get the chance.